# Mesh deform breaks when posing bones

Tags: mesh, modifiers, pose-mode

So iam trying out cloth simulations and i got this pretty sweet mesh deform ready, the proxy model around the high poly works fine and the cloth simulation transforms to the high poly mesh pretty nicely when i just move the armature around. But when get to actually animating the model(posing and adding keyframes) the mesh deform just decides to corrupt. The proxy model is doing things accordingly to the armature but the mesh deformer somehow just cant transfer it to the main mesh. Ive been trying to figure it out for about 5 hours.
Procedure:

1. made a low poly model that goes around the high poly part
   2.added back vertices to pin group
   3.added cloth simulation and added the pin group to pin
   4.added armature to the low poly and attached all vertices to R.chest
   5.added mesh deform to high poly model and selected the low poly as the source
2. just pressed g and moved it around when playing the animation(works perfectly)
   7.if i position any of the bones the mesh deform breaks, but the low poly is intact

Heres how it looks on keyframe 1:[image: keyframe 1]

and heres when the spine moves slightly:[image: keyframe 2]

i can send the .blend file if needed

**ALSO**: the surface deform modifier doesnt have this problem, looks pretty good, but there a weird jitter , and ive seen a lot people using the mesh modifier.

Comment: Can't say without seeing the file, but it looks like you're doing double deforms: once from the armature, then once from the mesh deformer.  Which is what you can expect if you armature deform and then mesh deform from a mesh that is also armature deformed.  If I wanted to do this, I would do it with a dynamic bind, and bone parent the mesh deformer rather than armature deform it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot dude! I didn't know theres a differrence between bone binding and armature deform... All the problems are gone! all i did is bind by bone.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix - Can't say without seeing the file, but it looks like you're doing double deforms: once from the armature, then once from the mesh deformer. Which is what you can expect if you armature deform and then mesh deform from a mesh that is also armature deformed. If I wanted to do this, I would do it with a dynamic bind, and bone parent the mesh deformer rather than armature deform it. –
Nathan 6 hours ago

As said, i just bone binded the proxy models, instead of armature deforming it....